Issue with Initializing Socket.io Once in a Node.js Clustered Environment with Express.js
I'm working on a Node.js application using the cluster module to handle multiple worker processes. My application uses Express.js for HTTP requests and Socket.io for real-time communication. The challenge I'm facing is ensuring that the Socket.io server is initialized only once in this clustered environment while maintaining proper functionality across all worker processes.
What I've Tried:
Socket.io Initialization: I understand that Socket.io should be initialized only once, ideally in the primary process, but I’m struggling to implement this in a way that works with clustering.
Cluster Setup: I’ve set up the cluster module to fork worker processes and attempted to initialize the Socket.io server within the primary process only.
Code Snippet:
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import os from 'os';
import httpServer from './app';
import config from './app/config';
import subscribeToJobs from './app/scheduler';
import { print } from './app/utils/colorizedConsole';

// handle uncaughtExceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  print.red('Uncaught Exception.... Process Terminated', err);
  process.exit(1);
});

let server: Server;

const numCPUs = os.availableParallelism();

async function main() {
  try {
    if (cluster.isPrimary) {
    await subscribeToJobs();
    // cluster module part
    print.blue(`Number of CPUs: ${numCPUs}`);
    print.green(`Primary process ${process.pid} is running`);
     for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
      cluster.fork();
     }
     cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
       print.yellow(
         `Worker process ${worker.process.pid} died. Restarting...`,
       );
       cluster.fork();
     });
     } else {
    server = httpServer.listen(config.port, () => {
      if (config.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        print.green(
          `✔ Server started at http://localhost:${config.port} pid: ${process.pid}`,
        );
      } else {
        print.green(`✔ Server started at ${config.port} pid: ${process.pid}`);
      }
    });
   }
  } catch (err) {
    print.red('Error starting server:', err);
  }

  // handle unHandledRejection
  process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    print.red('UNHANDLED REJECTION... . Process Terminated', err);

    if (server) {
      server.close(() => {
        process.exit(1);
      });
    } else {
      process.exit(1);
    }
  });
}

main();

process.on('SIGTERM', (err) => {
  print.yellow(' SIGTERM RECEIVED. Shutting down gracefully');
  server.close(() => {
    print.red(' Process terminated!', err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
});

App Configuration (Express.js with Socket.io):
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from 'express';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import hpp from 'hpp';
import http from 'http';
import httpStatus from 'http-status';
import moment from 'moment';
import globalError from './app/middlewares/globalError';
import morganLogger from './app/middlewares/morgan';
import router from './app/routes';
import socketServer from './app/socket/socketServer';
import sendResponse from './app/utils/sendResponse';

const app: Application = express();

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

socketServer.registerSocketServer(httpServer);

//global app middleware
app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:5173', 'https://frontend.illama360.com'],
    credentials: true,
  }),
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(hpp());

// logger
app.use(morganLogger);

//parsers
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api', router);

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const formattedDate = moment().format('DD MMMM YYYY hh.mm A');
  res.send(formattedDate);
});

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  sendResponse(res, {
    statusCode: httpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
    success: false,
    message: 'Address not found',
  });
});

app.use(globalError);

export default httpServer;


Socket Server Code:
import { Server } from 'http';
import { Server as SocketServer } from 'socket.io';

let io: SocketServer;

function registerSocketServer(httpServer: Server) {
  if (!io) {
    io = new SocketServer(httpServer);
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log(`Socket connected: ${socket.id}`);
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('Socket.io server is already initialized.');
  }
}

export default { registerSocketServer };


Expected Behavior:
The Socket.io server should initialize only once and work correctly across all worker processes without duplicating connections or encountering issues.
Actual Behavior:
Socket.io is either not initializing correctly across workers, or it initializes multiple times, leading to issues with connections.
Question:
How can I properly initialize Socket.io in a clustered Node.js environment with Express.js, ensuring it’s initialized only once and functions correctly across all worker processes? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
